# Dealing with multiple capture groups in multiple records

Tags: perl

**Data Format:**

```
attribname: data
```

**Data Example:**

```
cheese: good
pizza: good
bagel: good
fire: bad
```

**Code:**

```
my $subFilter='(.+?): (.+)';
my @attrib = ($dataSet=~/$subFilter/g);
for (@attrib)
{
   print "$_\n";
}
```

The code spits out:

```
cheese
good
pizza
good
[etc...]
```

I was wondering what an easy Perly way to do this is? I am parsing the data from a log the data above is trash for simplicity. I am newer to Perl, I suspect I could do this via fanangling indexes, but I was wondering if there is a short method of implementing this? Is there any way to have the capture groups put into two different variables instead of serially appended to the list along with all matches?

**Edit:** I want the attribute and it's associated value together so I can the do what I need to to them. For example if within my for loop I could access both the attribute name and attribute value.

**Edit:**

I tried

```
my %attribs;
while (my $line = <$data>)
{
     my ($attrib, $value) = ($line=~m/$subFilter/);
     print $attribs{$attrib}," : ", $value,"\n";
}
```

and no luck :( I don't get any output with this. My data is in a variable not a file, because it parsed out of a set of parent data which is in a file. It would be convenient if the my variable worked so that `my (@attrib, @value) = ($line=~/$subFilter/g);` filled the lists appropriately with the multiple matches.

Solution:

```
my @line = ($7 =~/(.+?)\n/g);
for (@line)
{
  my ($attrib, $value) = ($_=~m/$subFilter/);
  if ($attrib ne "")
  {
     print $attrib," : ", $value,"\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: The code posted under 'Solution' does not completely reflect the needs mentioned in the original scope of the problem. If you are expecting to have some empty attribute fields, it would be a good idea to let others know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you actually want to store, but here's how you could store the data in a hash table, with '1' indicating good and '0' indicating 'bad':

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %foods;
while (my $line = <DATA>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my ($food, $good) = ($line =~ m/^(.+?): (.+)$/);
    $foods{$food} = ($good eq 'good' ? 1 : 0);
}

print Dumper(\%foods);

__DATA__
cheese: good
pizza: good
bagel: good
fire: bad
```

This prints:

```
$VAR1 = { 
          'bagel' => 1,
          'cheese' => 1,
          'fire' => 0,
          'pizza' => 1
        };
```

Comment: I'm trying some of what you commented here. The my ($food, $good) = ($line =~ m/^(.+?): (.+)$/); was something I learned from your post. That is close to what I am needing.

Answer (score 0):

A sensible approach would be to make use of the [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function:

```
my %attrib;

open my $data, '<', 'fileName' or die "Unable to open file: $!";

while ( my $line = <$data> ) {

    my ( $attrib, $value ) = split /:\s*/, $line, 2;
    $attrib{$attrib} = $value;
}

close $data;

foreach my $attrib ( keys %attrib ) {

    print "$attrib: $attrib{$attrib}\n";
}
```

If you're into one-liners, the following would achieve the same:

```
$ perl -F/:\s*/ -ane '$attrib{$F[0]} = $F[1]; } END { print $_,"\t",$attrib{$_},"\n" foreach keys %attrib;" fileName
```